# PatchOrchestrationApplicationType 1.2.2 - FABRIC_E_FILE_NOT_FOUND: The Application Manifest file 'ApplicationManifest.xml' is not found in the store

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I have deployed a Service Fabric cluster with the Patch Orchestration application with version 1.2.1 using ARM following the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-patch-orchestration-application), it was successful without any issues with package 1.2.1. But same thing I tried with the package with the version 1.2.2, it is giving me an error "FABRIC_E_FILE_NOT_FOUND: The Application Manifest file 'ApplicationManifest.xml' is not found in the store."

Is it a known issue or could anyone help me out in this?

Thanks,
Avinash

Comment: share the template or something?

Comment: I used below script to download the latest app package: 

**$url = "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=869566"
$output = "C:\temp\PatchOrchestrationApplication_v1.2.2.sfpkg"
Write-Host "Downloading the application package from the internet..."
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $output**

And I have stored that package in the storage on the cloud and using it while deployment in **appPackageURL**.

The link for ARM: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-arm-resource

Comment: this template doesnt work as is, it doesnt even pass the download uri to the rest call

Comment: Yes it doesn't work as is, hence I added the PowerShell code to get the latest app package and then store it on the cloud and then make use of that package using the URI of stored location. It is working with 1.2.1 version but not with 1.2.2.
I have just found the folder structure change in 1.2.1 and 1.2.2, and they are different hence it's not working with 1.2.2.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the issue was due to a different folder structure of the downloaded content. for me just changing the version to 1.2.2 and the url to the new version worked for the template.

Comment: You are right. The folder structure is different for 1.2.2 and hence it was giving me an error. I wrote some code to extract the sfpkg and get all content to the root folder and zip it back. Then it's working.
Thank you, I appreciate you helped!